# Make messageBar critical messages permanent

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, error, qgis-2.18

The default for messages generated with `self.iface.messageBar().pushCritical()` is to remain on screen for a set duration. I would like them to keep being displayed as long as the user has not closed them by clicking on "x", but I don't know how to do that.

I also tried using `pushMessage()`instead of `pushCritical()`, as it allows you to specify a duration and thus could make the message "permanent" if I specified a very long duration, but I can't get it to work. The instruction

```
self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage(u'Error : ', u' My error message.', level=QgsMessageBar.CRITICAL, duration=999)
```

gets me the following error in the console : 
*NameError: global name 'QgsMessageBar' is not defined*. 
I don't understand what the problem is, I used `from PyQt4.QtGui import *` at the beginning of my script...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[QgsMessageBar](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMessageBar.html) comes from the `qgis.gui` module, not from `PyQt4.QtGui` :)

So you could use something like the following:

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMessageBar

self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage(u'Error : ', u' My message.', level = QgsMessageBar.CRITICAL, duration=0)
```

Where the integer `0` indicates a no timeout (i.e. no duration).